# With RSpec, how do I write an expression that captures _spec files in nested directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, glob, ruby-on-rails-6, circleci

I’m using Rails 6 with RSpec 3.10.  I have the following directory structure

```
spec/models/my_object_spec.rb
spec/models/module_name/product_spec.rb
```

I run the tests with a command similar to the below

```
bundle exec rspec --color --require spec_helper --format RspecJunitFormatter --out $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/rspec/rspec.xml --format progress $(circleci tests glob spec/**/*_spec.rb | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
```

The issue is that the regular expression “spec/**/*_spec.rb” only seems to run the file “spec/models/my_object_spec.rb”, however, the other file in the child directory of “models” doesn’t get run.  Is there a way to write the regular expression so that it would capture all files ending in “_spec” regardless of which child directory they are in?

Comment: a glob is not a regex. you need to enable `globstar` in order for circleci to recurse correctly: `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with .circleci, but I included a "- run: shopt -s globstar" in the config right before my rspec command (listed in the question) and after running a build my specs in teh nested directories were still not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glob is not a regex, so you need to enable the shell-option `globstar` in order to recurse subdirectories.

Adding the line `- run: shopt -s globstar` before your test call won't work because each step in CircleCI runs it in its own shell instance. You need to set the shell-opt in the same step that you run your tests. Something like this:

```yaml
- run:
  command: |
    shopt -s globstar
    bundle exec rspec --color --require spec_helper --format RspecJunitFormatter --out $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/rspec/rspec.xml --format progress $(circleci tests glob spec/**/*_spec.rb | circleci tests split --split-by=timings)
```